# Is there a CPAN module to parse nested parentheses?

Tags: perl, cpan

Is there a CPAN module that can read a string like this:

```
"[[<asdf>, <foo>], (abc, def, ghi), ({'jkl'})]"
```

...and parse it into some sort of tree structure that's easy to walk and pretty-print?

Answer (score 9):

I think that you could build on top of [Text::Balanced](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Balanced/), which will do a lot of the heavy lifting for you. You'll still need to build a tree structure, though.

Answer (score 4):

Perl 5.10's regular expressions can handle balanced structures like that. See the `(?PARNO) (?-PARNO) (?+PARNO) (?R) (?0)` section in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Answer (score 2):

[Perl 6](http://dev.perl.org/perl6/doc/design/apo/A05.html) is going to have built-in facilities to help support this.  In the interim, Text::Balanced (as mentioned by Dave Rolsky) is probably the module of choice.  Note that it, too, was written by Damian Conway (as commended by Bill Karwin).

Answer (score 1):

[Damian Conway's Parse::RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parse::RecDescent)

I haven't used this, but it's a good bet that a Perl module written by Damian Conway is worth using.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is identical to the [Data Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) format, then it can be `eval`-ed back into the original structure.

Comment: That's actually a neat idea, if you're sure the input is valid and all that. Thanks. Edit: Perl's auto-flattening would potentially lose a lot of info from the input though.